# How will I know specifically when the tasks in my packages have run successfully in SSIS also how can I show that in a log tablet in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, monitor, sql-server-agent, msbi

Let's there is a master package and several tasks run in it on a daily basis, I want to specifically determine when those tasks have finished like table load completed and cuble load completed, these steps run daily but I have to show this in a SQL table that this particular day table load started at this time and ended at this like etc

Comment: Does [This](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-ssis-package-logging/) help?

Comment: Are you deploying the the SSISDB? If so, that data is already captured for you

Answer (score 0):

> SSIS event handlers are the simplest means of turning an SSIS script
> into a reliable system that is auditable, reacts appropriately to
> error conditions, reports progress and allows instrumentation and
> monitoring your SSIS packages. They are easy to implement, and provide
> a great deal of flexibility. Rob Sheldon once again provides the easy,
> clear introduction.

You can use on PostExecute and when the tasks runs successfully :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or you can use containers and then use precedence constraints with success and failure
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFsoW.png]